# How can I use autowiring with class created from string in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Messenger in Symfony to send request to create archive of documents

In controller action:

```
$bus->dispatch(
    new ArchiveRequest(
        \App\Archiving\SomeSpecialArchiveBuilder::class,
        $this->getRequestJsonContent()
    )
);
```

In `ArchiveRequestHandler` I want somehow to instantiate this special class and autowire services to it.

```
class ArchiveRequestHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(
        ArchiveRequest $archiveRequest
    )
    {
        // How can I instantiate special implementation of ArchiveBuilderInterface here and autowire services from container?
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't inject the instance directly in `ArchiveRequest`?

Comment: If I try to typehint certain archive builder in action like SomeSpecialArchiveBuilder $builder and use like

        $bus->dispatch(
            new ArchiveRequest(
                $builder, 
                $this->getRequestJsonContent()
            )
        );

I get "exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

Comment: I think I won't be able to serialize the $builder cause it's very complex

Comment: If you want to instantiate the class within the handler, then you cannot use autowiring. You could use some sort of service locator, though. The handler should have the service locator injected, and get the service from there.